# how to call one directive controller function from another one directive using angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

> I got error while sharing one controller between two directive..it
>   just throw unidentifier error.i have mention below, what's wrong with my code.

**My directive Code:**

```
gateApp.directive('parentctrldir', function(){
    return{
        restrict : 'E',
        link : function(scope, elem, attrs){

        },
        controller : function($scope){
            this.callfunction = function(){
                alert('hi uu');
            }
        }
    }
});
gateApp.directive('derivedctrldir', function(){
    return{
        restrict : 'E',
        require : '^parentctrldir',
        link : function(scope, elem, attrs, parentctrldirController){
            parentctrldirController.callfunction();
        },

    }
});
```

**my .gsp page:**

```
<parentctrldir></parentctrldir>
<derivedctrldir></derivedctrldir>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should have a nested structure in your HTML:

```
<parentctrldir>
    <derivedctrldir></derivedctrldir>
</parentctrldir>
```

In [AngularJS example](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive#creating-directives-that-communicate) `my-tabs` wraps `my-pane` (see `index.html` tab).

Comment: i have use this custom directive in grails groovy page.i don't have .html page.extension is .gsp.and also have applied your idea..but not working.i'm battling with this require concept.

Comment: ya you are correct..i also make a mistake, i leave comma in deriveddir..now working fine.